# Can someone explain why does these terms get cancel out while deriving Riemann curvature tensor from geodesic deviation?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, curvature, geodesics

I was trying to derive Riemann curvature tensor from geodesic deviation and I came across these terms with the derivatives of seperation vector. I made some research and seems like they should cancel out but I couldn't understand why or how. Could you help me?

[image]

Comment: The text says that the “terms in second order with respect to $\xi$” are discarded, that means they would behave like $\mathcal{O}(|\xi|^2)$ and would be small relative to those linear in $\xi$ as $\xi \to 0$.

Comment: I have read the text. But I hadn't understood the "terms in second order with respect to epsilon " part before you said it. Is it because of the derivatives? Since epsilon is infinitesimal its derivative  approaches zero as epsilon approaches zero and because both of them are approaching zero means it can be written as epsilon squared? Is it why they cancel out? Do I get it right?

Comment: I mean epsilon squared becomes negligible because of Taylor expansion. Is it why they cancel out ? Am I right?? Thank you for your time.

Comment: It's not “epsilon” it is “xi”, as in $\xi^{\mu}$, the separation between two geodesics. And no, it is not about derivatives, it is about products of two things linear in “xi” inside each of the cancelled terms.

Comment: I think it may help to clarify @A.V.S. 's point to note that in the final line the whole thing is already multiplied by a factor of $\xi$, so "first order" stuff in the parentheses is actually second order.

Comment: My bad about the notation, I am a little new to the subject. So I know xi's higher order terms are smaller and negligible and in the final line whole thing is already multiplied by a xi. So what I deduce is that if xi's second order terms get canceled out it is because a derivative of xi behave like xi itself. Do I get it right?

Comment: "cancel out" is a bad way of saying it. "Can be  neglected" is better.

Comment: Is my way of thinking valid in this case?